# Can Web API acts as MassTransit Consumer?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, masstransit

I am new to MassTransit and trying to understand how it works.

I am having a windows service consumer which consumer messages from RabbitMQ.

I would like to move that to Web API.

https://masstransittemp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/locations.html#configuring-masstransit-in-a-web-application

Can the Web API constantly listen to RabbitMQ and consumer messages?

What are the best practices and efficient ways to deal with Masstransit and Web API?

Comment: At this point, you'd be better served by a Worker in .NET Core 3.0. See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/. That's specifically about hosting as a windows service, but there's more hosting options now at this point.

Comment: you can also see the setup of Web API and MassTransit here: https://github.com/MassTransit/TheCoffeeShop/tree/master/src/TheCoffeeShop.Api

Comment: @ChrisPatterson can you please explain more? So, we don't need windows/wcf services to listen to RabbitMQ messaging? and Web API can do it ?

Comment: The sample I linked has it all built out, you can use the Generic Host of ASP.NET Core to include a hosted service. Also, your documentation link is ancient, the current documentation is here: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/